Spread positive value across columns
In an Excel spreadsheet, I take a weekly inventory of items and subtract it from a needs list to create orders for the week.
I want:
If difference between G-F is positive, spread the number needed into the four columns.
If G-F is negative then 0.
I can move columns around if needed.

I tried a few SpreadEven VBA codes I found online. I was unable to make the needed adjustments to make it work.
